# Как присвоить строке дату?

Tags: php

Есть переменная $birthday
Как сделать так, чтобы этой переменной можно было передавать только строку в формате "год-месяц-день"

Comment: может не переменной а все таки функции?

Comment: Нет, мне нужна строка именно с датой, чтобы я в дальнейшем смог оперировать ею для вычисления количества лет пользователя, например

Comment: можете навести пример кода? как вы хотите, чтоб это выглядело?

Comment: Вот тут, Задача № 3
http://code.mu/ru/php/book/oop/overriding-of-parent-constructor/

Comment: Надо реализовать метод/функцию, которая валидировала бы входные данные. При успешной валидации записать значение в переменную. Тут можно и date formatting почитать в официальной документации.

Answer (score 0):

Создаем класс

```
class MySuperDateClass
{
    private $date;

    public function setDate($date)
    {
        if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/",$date)) {
            $this->date = $date;
        } else {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("invalid date format");
        }
    }


}
```

Создаем его экземпляр и пробуем присвоить дату

```
$myClass = new MySuperDateClass();

try {
    $myClass->setDate('1996-11-29');
    echo 'Success';
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $exception) {
    echo $exception->getMessage();
}
```